# Docusign REST API - SFOpportunity

Tags: docusignapi

I'm integrating with a partner who currently uses Sales Force to send documents (templates) via Docusign.

I'm able to send the template using the REST API correctly, however, I'm unable to associate the document with Sales Force.  I've found various resources using either APEX or the SOAP API, but nothing specifically for the REST API.

We've verified that Docusign Connect is enabled for my user and I've added ##SFOpportunity and it's value to the custom fields of my envelope.

Currently, my request looks like the following:

```
"accountId": "14618496",
"emailSubject": "Direct Information - Action Required",
"emailBlurb": "Hello!",
"templateId": "1F89397C-5555-45BD-94C3-7372AAFDE719",
"customFields": {
    "customField": [
        {
            "name": "##SFOpportunity",
            "value": "555i000000SfGTqAAN"
        },
        {
            "name": "##SFAccount",
            "value": "555i000000mL4CMAA0"
        },
        {
            "name": "##SFContract",
            "value": "555i000000nDWlkAAG"
        }
    ]
},
"templateRoles": [
    {
        "email": null,
        "name": " John",
        "roleName": "Signer 1",
        "tabs": {
            "textTabs": [
                {
                    "tabLabel": "\\*Company Name",
                    "value": "Test"
                },
                {
                    "tabLabel": "\\*Address",
                    "value": "123 Test St"
                },
                {
                    "tabLabel": "\\*City",
                    "value": "Vista"
                },
                {
                    "tabLabel": "\\*State",
                    "value": "CA"
                },
                {
                    "tabLabel": "\\*Remittance Contact:",
                    "value": "Test"
                },
                {
                    "tabLabel": "\\*Remittance Email",
                    "value": null
                },
                {
                    "tabLabel": "\\*Title",
                    "value": null
                },
                {
                    "tabLabel": "\\*Full Name",
                    "value": "Test Test"
                }
            ],
            "numberTabs": [
                {
                    "tabLabel": "\\*Zip Code",
                    "value": "92084"
                },
                {
                    "tabLabel": "\\*Telephone",
                    "value": "7145559555"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
],
"status": "sent"
```

In the above example, I'm setting custom field variables to the envelope, and I'm not receiving any errors from document for this request.

How do I properly format my request to associate the Opportunity, Account, etc to the document?

Comment: You just need to setup your Connect rules to grab that custom tag and associate it properly. Which isn't a programming question, it's more of a how-to use DocuSign Connect question.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Since this is for a partner, I'm unable to access the Docusign Connect questions, so I'm flying blind on that side of things.  I looked at the [Connect documentation Guide](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/connect-guide.pdf) but I didn't see anything that jumped out at me.  Are you familiar enough with it to point me in the right direction?

Comment: You would have to check the impacted account's Connect settings. It's 100% flying blind without that info :\